# Why does this simple moment.js logic cause an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, infinite-loop

#### This code creates an infinite loop.

| Changing the `<=` to just a `<` does not create an infinite loop.

```js
var s_date = "2020-05-07";
var e_date = "2020-12-31";

for (
  var i = 0;
  Number(moment(s_date).add(i, "M").format("M")) <=
  Number(moment(e_date).format("M"));
  i++
) {
  var month = moment(s_date).add(i, "M").format("MMM");
  console.log(month, moment(e_date).format("MMM"));
}
```

### OUTPUT:

```
May Dec
Jun Dec
Jul Dec
Aug Dec
Sep Dec
Oct Dec
Nov Dec
Dec Dec
Jan Dec
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deeper idea is that dates are quantities, and formatted strings aren't, even when coerced into Numbers. Use `diff` to measure quantitative differences, and factor out loop invariant code to be more efficient and readable.

```js
const s_date = "2020-05-07";
const e_date = "2020-12-31";

let mStart = moment(s_date);
let mEnd = moment(e_date);

for (
  let mDate = mStart.clone();
  mEnd.diff(mDate, "M") > 0;
  mDate.add(1, "M")
) {
  console.log(mDate.format("MMM"), mEnd.format("MMM"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Number(moment(e_date).format("M"))` is 11.

`Number(moment(s_date).add(i, "M").format("M"))` is in the range [0, 11].

`x <= 11` is true for all `x` in [0, 11].

```
Number(moment(s_date).add(i, "M").format("M")) <= Number(moment(e_date).format("M"))
```

is always true.

It's like

```
for (let i = 0; (5 + i) % 12 <= 11; i++) // infinite loop
```

and

```
for (let i = 0; (5 + i) % 12 < 11; i++) // leaves loop for i == 6
```